# Best way to draw attention to someone else's good question?

Tags: discussion, questions

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789305/ruby-date-strptime-doesnt-enforce-4-digit-year/24789349?noredirect=1#24789305) asked by another user which is IMHO an excellent question.

It is:

- Concise
- Clear
- Not readily answered by using Google

In fact, at this point it looks like the problem may be in the language interpreter itself.  The question was scored at 1.  I then upvoted it, but it was briefly down to 0 for a bit.  As of this writing it's back to 1.  I believe (based on comments) that the downvoters misunderstood what was being asked.

So the question I have is twofold:

First, how do I go about bringing attention to a question that I think is very high quality?  I'm aware posting this on meta will probably do the trick, but it'd be nice if there were a generic way of doing that.
Second, and maybe this should be asked first, is bringing attention to such a question something that actually needs to be done?

Comment: You can put a bounty on it, or you can post a link to it on social media. In other words, exactly like you'd draw attention to your own question.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think it's /that/ high quality to begin with

Comment: If the people reading the question aren't understanding it then *by definition* it's not a great question.  Great questions are clear and understandable.  If people aren't understanding it, then it's not a clear and understandable question.  It may be able to *become* a good question, if it is edited to improve its clarity.

Comment: That question was answered 45 minutes before you wrote this meta post, and an answer has already been accepted by the OP. Why do you need to bring attention to it?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by giving the question attention? It's already answered.

Comment: @Servy I honestly felt it was unambiguously worded despite the confusion.  I'm not sure how it could have been rewritten to be clearer.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I felt the guy deserved upvotes.  Also, I was wondering for the more generic case, when there might not have been an answer already.

Comment: Best way to give a chance to a question you like: don't mention it on Meta.SO :-)

Comment: @Bruno one of the less helpful answers was downvoted and has since been removed, so it helped a little bit.  But I'll keep this bit of advice in mind for the future.

Comment: @servy - no.  Many misunderstandings come from readers who are out of their area of expertise, and jump to wildly incorrect conclusion as a result.  The real question is if the intended audience - those with the topic expertise to contribute an answer - understand it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Checklist for neglected questions

1. Wait at least a week before taking action (after all, if it's your own question, you could earn the [Tumbleweed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed)).
2. During the course of this waiting period, edit it if you come across new information. This will bump it back to the top of the question list (only applies if it's your own question: don't suggest edits solely to bump posts). Edits are important, because a question that is unclear or low-quality is usually not worth answering since the likelihood of its deletion is high. Also make sure you've tagged it correctly, because the way you tag a question determines who sees it, and that can have a large impact on who answers it (or doesn't).
3. After a week, if you *really* want an answer to a question, add a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).
4. If the bounty expires and it still hasn't been answered sufficiently, add a bounty (must be at least double the amount of the first).
5. Repeat #4 until you reach a 500 rep bounty (well, you can keep offering 500 rep bounties if you'd like, but that's a bit ridiculous)
6. If you've made it this far and still don't have a sufficient answer, then something is wrong. Either it is unsolvable, it's been tagged improperly, or it's unclear. Usually, if you're willing to give away 500+ rep for a good answer, someone's willing to do the research to give one (though the absence of good answers may attract a few low-quality answers trying to get the automatically-awarded half-bounty with two upvotes). If you've gotten to this point and it's due to difficulty, I'd recommend self-answering if you ever solve the problem, because it will likely be a *very* useful future source (and an interesting post to reference on Meta).

Posting something about a question on Meta will certainly gain it attention, but 1) it may not be the kind of attention you wanted and 2) it's inappropriate to do so unless it is a crucial part of a question about something that's [on-topic for Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Also, you can share the question on social media networks and via email by clicking [image: share] below the post. This will generate a unique URL that can earn you the [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer), [Booster](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster), and [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist) badges for 25, 300, and 1000 visits from unique IP addresses respectively.

[image]

I also recommend taking a look at [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) about bounties on Meta.SE.

Comment: About 1.  "This badge is retired and is no longer awarded."

Comment: "only applies if it's your own question: don't suggest edits solely to bump posts" - don't suggest edits solely to bump a question regardless of whether it was asked by you or someone else.

Answer (score -9):

You can click on one of the tag, find some questions relevant to yours, then post your question as a link on the answers you like most. This will increase the chance your question is read by an expert interesting to the topic. I'm not sure if this is spamming or not, but I think it's beneficial for everyone: you, the people you "spam", future readers whose interest aligns with yours.

Comment: This is abusive behavior and is not at all acceptable.

Comment: Can you explain why? I see many people refer to their own questions, and it seems natural for me

Comment: Referring to a question in a comment because it's relevant to improving the post you're commenting on is fine.  Linking to another post isn't universally wrong.  Going around to random posts to just link to yours and ask people to answer is is just intentionally spamming, not attempting to improve the post you're commenting on.

Comment: I don't go "around to random posts to just link to" mine, I spent *hours*, even *days* to read those questions and answers before asking, and wait for a week before doing that. In the meantime I find the answers myself. While this is not directly improving the post, it does expand and generalize the problems, and does improve the understanding of everyone. For more background, I come to this question by Google, and have a mindset of doing math rather than coding. I'm sorry if I'm in defensive mode.

Comment: That you spent the time to read other questions/answers or that you waited a while before posting your spam on them doesn't make it any more appropriate to post your spam.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't appropriate to post spam, but it's a follow up question, not a spam. (See [Should I invite other users to answer my question in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269594/3416774)). Can you answer to the point about the generalization of the problems?

Comment: No, you're not describing follow up questions.  You're suggesting going around to other random questions linking to yours, not posting a follow up question.

Comment: For reference, do you think [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055559/why-m%c3%b6bius-transformation-is-isomorphic-to-projective-linear-group#comment5201383_1056871) is a follow up question? Assuming that it is the link to my question, is it still spamming?

Comment: That's outside of my area of expertise, so I couldn't comment on whether or not that's asking a question about the answer posted or not.

Comment: In general, any question does enrich the understanding of the topic, then [why should we discourage it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269588/should-i-invite-other-users-to-answer-my-question-in-comments/269594#comment531761_269594). If there is a whole post behind the link, then isn't it further enriching the question?

Comment: "any question does enrich the understanding of the topic" That's a false premise, and so your conclusion isn't merited.  It does not benefit any question to link to another question from it.  In fact, it detracts from it in most cases.

Comment: What if I always ask with the spirit "my questions must contribute to the understanding of the topic, and it is natural for me to do so"? Would there be a case that the follow-up question with that spirit does not benefit at all?

Comment: Yes, and that case is every single one.

Comment: Why isn't contributing to the common understanding benefit at all?

Comment: Why *would* it contribute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158899/discussion-between-ooker-and-servy).

Comment: What you describe here, finding experts that might be able to answer, then pointing to your question in a comment on answer they wrote is *indeed considered harassment*. Do not do that. You've only done this once, luckily, and I deleted that comment. As you can see from the community votes on your answer, this is not something we want to see advocated as a good idea.