# A user left a comment on my unrelated answer about my close vote

Tags: discussion, comments, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

Just a little while ago, I got a comment on [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028280/how-to-add-specific-values-in-a-column-sql/31028315?noredirect=1#comment50177659_31028315) from a user about reopening that user's [question which I voted to close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004995/anonymize-amazon-public-url-decode-using-a-script-on-nginx]).  The answer is not related to that user's question.

> Just following up with you for putting a question on hold. [stackoverflow.com/questions/31004995/… (stackoverflow.com/questions/31004995/…) Can you please remove the hold if this question has be crafted properly. If you have already voted for reopen then please ignore this message.

It seems that this user left the same comment for other users who also voted to close the question.

This happened very first time to me. What is the community's thinking on this?

Comment: Flag - Not Constructive. Or Other. If you're really feeling generous you could even check out the question.

Comment: Yes, I flagged that comment

Comment: Quite similar to [Can I ask "please look at my other question"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269588/2564301) (which got answered with a hearthy "No!").

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's up to you.

You can ignore it. That's fine.

You can check the question and if you think it's been improved enough you can vote to reopen. That's fine too, but not what I'd do. If the OP has edited the question it will have been placed in the reopen queue anyway.

However, if I were to see such a comment or if it were flagged I'd deleted it straight away. Comments should not be used to badger other users about *anything* - accepting answers, answering other questions etc, etc.

So, please ignore such comments and flag them as "not constructive" so that they can be deleted.

Comment: Yes, I voted this comment so that mods can remove

Comment: Well, there's a case for notifying the *single* user who just then cast a binding vote that he was mistaken, and how. Which would naturally happen on the question itself, not on some unrelated post.