# How duplicate questions can be marked as not-duplicate, after editing to show the difference

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

I had asked a question on SO: [Denying PHP Script To run within certain folder but still making it downloadable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425524/denying-php-script-to-run-within-certain-folder-but-still-making-it-downloadable)

at that time the question wasn't clear and was using different tags like: `wamp`,`.htaccess` and `httpd.conf`.

thus it was marked as duplicate of: [Disable PHP in directory (including all sub-directories) with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271899/disable-php-in-directory-including-all-sub-directories-with-htaccess)

Since both were same.

But now I've edited that question and mentioned the difference between two. What I have to do remove the question as dupe? and how long it'll take to become that question as non dupe? also should I ask a new question to get more attention?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: @gnat It wasn't wrongly marked as dupe. at that time it was. But now it isn't.

Comment: consider [edit]ing your question to clarify this. As currently written, it reads as about wrongly-marked dupes: "What I have to do remove the question as dupe? and how long it'll take to become that question as non dupe?"

Comment: @VedantTerkar The question has *never* been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy , gnat Edited the question. Thanks for your attention btw.

Comment: "It wasn't wrongly marked as dupe. at that time it was [a dupe]. But now it isn't." Just like this question. Irony, anyone?

Comment: Don't change the question. Same rules apply as on SO. It makes answers and comments invalid and confusing. If you have a new question...post a new question. Also, your new question has been answered on here. Edit to make it more clear, share on other sites, and bounty

Comment: FWIW, [rev 3 of this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/272523/3) seems to be a duplicate of [What do I do if my question has received no answers or comments?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261078/what-do-i-do-if-my-question-has-received-no-answers-or-comments) and [Reasking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270193/reasking-a-question) (the latter also answers part of the question as it's currently written)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265874/best-way-to-draw-attention-to-someone-elses-good-question

Answer (score 5):

The question *isn't* closed as a duplicate, and never was. Someone simply posted a comment to a related question for you to look into.

Comment: Thank you. But what about second part: `should I ask a new question to get more attention?`

Comment: Not if your new question would be a duplicate of the old. editing should be enough to bring it more attention, and if not, there's always bounties

Comment: @VedantTerkar No you should not re-ask your question just because you don't yet have an answer you like.

Comment: @Servy , & KevinB Thank you guys. That helped me.