# Best ways to draw attention to high-quality questions in minor tags

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

Very closely related: [Best way to draw attention to someone else's good question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265874/best-way-to-draw-attention-to-someone-elses-good-question)

My question is similar, except that I'm asking specifically what to do if the only applicable tags are poorly trafficked. Many of the things that would be likely to work with a highly trafficked tag like C#, Java, or Python are much less likely to be helpful in smaller tags.

I recently encountered an especially interesting [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762213/what-characters-show-on-notepad-but-not-on-browser) regarding "hidden" characters. Unfortunately, it hasn't received much attention due to being in "small" tags. I was having trouble identifying more trafficked tags that apply to it.

The obvious things to do would be to edit it to improve its quality and "bump" it, upvote to signal that the question's worth reading, add additional relevant tags, or to start a bounty on it. (I did all of the above except start a bounty on it).

A lot of those are less helpful in smaller tags, though; for example, editing to improve and "bump" a question is only helpful if people are actually reading the tag on a regular basis. It also seems like a bounty wouldn't necessarily be all *that* helpful given that the tags that apply aren't all that well-trafficked.

**Edit:** The comments mentioned that you could still filter on questions that have bounties in general, so adding a bounty *could* still draw attention to the question even if very few people follow the tag, but it seems like people don't necessarily do that. Personally, I only look for questions with bounties in tags that I follow. The fact that a question has a bounty on it doesn't make me any more likely to know the answer to a PHP question given that I've never actually worked in the language. On the other hand, I'm *much* more likely to know the answer to a C# or Java question. That being said, I generally don't bother to look at questions with bounties on them in general - just in tags on subjects that I have prior experience in.

In cases like this, what are other things that you can do?

Comment: That question seems pretty broad to me. What browsers? What versions of Notepad?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I checked it using Notepad in Windows 10, Firefox 52.4.0, and IE 11 and saw the behavior the question describes in all of them.

Comment: Adding tags that aren't related or even say "DO NOT USE" is a very nice step, yes. And like Alexander wrote, this question is rather broad, but also hardly programming related. _Might_ be on-topic on general CS sites regarding character encoding  or on web development sites ... _might_.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of the linked question. Adding more relevant tags is the only thing specific to tags and it's rather obvious. If none can be added, nothing specific can be done, it's not well-trafficked because people are not interested, that's just how it is.

Comment: *"I'm looking for a list…"* [is not how a good, on-topic question starts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Editing would be the first step, if you can imagine any way that the question could be salvaged to comply with our requirements.

Comment: Bounty questions show up under the bounty questions list regardless of what tags you follow; the list shows bountied questions from all tags.

Comment: "I did all of the above except start a bounty on it." A bounty would probably have worked best, even in low-traffic tags. (Unless you have a programming blog with thousands of regular readers.)

Comment: @TylerH True, but personally I don't pay any attention to bounties outside of the tags that I follow - I've always seen it as kind of pointless. The odds of me knowing the answer to a C# or Java question are much higher than me knowing the answer to a PHP question.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate because it seems that you're looking for an alternative solution that doesn't exist to a question that's already been answered.

Comment: @Dukeling I already explained how my question differs from that one.

Comment: "How do I start a Mercedes" is different from but still a duplicate of "How do I start a car" (IMO).

Comment: @Dukeling It's only a duplicate if the procedure for starting a Mercedes is the same as starting any other car.

Comment: Or perhaps it would've been better to compare it to "How do I get to the top of a big mountain" versus "How do I get to the top of a mountain".

Comment: @Dukeling The procedure for climbing Everest is actually a *lot* different than the procedure for climbing a small mountain.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with the closure here. Just because a question doesnt have an answer _yet_ does not mean it should be closed as a duplicate of a question that does not contain an answer to this question. If the answer is "there is no way" that would then be an appropriate answer. cc@Dukeling