# Best way to draw attention to a good answer

Tags: discussion, answers

> Similar, but different: [Best way to draw attention to someone else's good question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265874/best-way-to-draw-attention-to-someone-elses-good-question)

We've all put time and effort into researching, duplicating, debugging tricky questions, often left unanswered for months or years.

Sometimes we stumble across them:

- A perfect answer to an obscure problem
- A detailed explanation to an unusual inquiry
- A response to a language/framework that's seldom used

**All of these are cases where, though the answer may shine brightly, it will rarely be seen.**

I've done a [few answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52032958/2656614) [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52323857/2656614) myself, which take a lot of time and effort, but don't get any votes, and may never be accepted (as the user is long-gone).

Is there a way to bring these questions to light? Is there a forum where we can let people know:

> "Hey, I just found an *outstanding* answer on [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/2656614) with barely any votes. I think it's *interesting*, and it shows research + effort. Take a look!"

Comment: 1) Make sure that the question is tagged correctly and specifically. 2) Make sure that the question is well-titled. Those are likely the best way to bring relevant traffic to the question

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Good response, but note that this is more targeted at a question which has already been answered. Specifically, it's regarding the answer to it. The dot points I listed above specify reasons why many questions will never get traffic, **despite** being well titled and tagged.

Comment: You are right, it is targeted at a question, but it is the question which draws the eyes, since they are the only part of the whole construct that has labels, title, etc... Even though you may not be the question author, you often can still work to improve the question as noted above and in other ways, to help increase traffic to it.

Comment: Related: [Best way to draw attention to someone else's good question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265874)

Comment: Below the answer you have what we call "Share" menu. It seems an underrated feature that most people overlook. Try sharing it to social media you might not expect how far it can reach.

Comment: Addison - 1000% agree with you. The discovery part of S.O. is terrible. The only answers that get rewarded have to be on the site for years and generate significant pull with Google. Pretty much everything else disappears immediately after posting it. I think this is a big reason S.O. has trouble attracting new devs who would contribute some good answers: it will be years before they have any rep in the community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not every good answer is going to get that many votes, and that's to be expected, depending on what you mean by "good". If you define "good" in this context to mean "useful", (which makes sense considering the text on the upvote button says "This answer is useful"), then there's more to it than whether or not the answer is well thought out, well written, and correct.

A significant part of what determines the general *usefulness* of an answer is whether or not people are likely to use it. A fantastic answer to an obscure problem will be *extremely* useful to the few people who encounter the problem, but because not many people will need it, it's not that useful to the world in general.

Most answers with a lot of votes accumulate them naturally over time as people find them while searching for solutions to their problems. The answers in the cases you described don't get many views or votes because they're answers to questions that other people don't have. That's not to say that those questions shouldn't be answered, but expecting to be rewarded with lots of votes is likely to be disappointing regardless of how much effort you put into the answer, or how much you're able to advertise the question.

Comment: The end of the story: Answer the questions, that are interesting to you (or were interesting to you sometimes), and the upvotes comes naturaly.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt and if they don't, be content with a job well done, and the knowledge that you may have prevented [this scenario](https://xkcd.com/979/) for someone in the future. ;)

Answer (score 19):

> All of these are cases where, though the answer may shine brightly, it
>   will rarely be seen.

That may be because of the question. If an answer is useful, but the question it is posted as an answer to is poorly formulated, lacks the proper tags or keywords that make it show up in searches, or is just unclear, then the bright and good answer might not actually seen by the people who need to see it.

> Is there a way to bring these questions to light? Is there a forum
>   where we can let people know:

There are two:

- Edit the question to make it clearer, add relevant tags
- Put a "reward existing answer" bounty on the question (for other people's answers)

Comment: Yes a bounty is a good solution, not only because the poster will get rep, but because the question will be featured for a week, so the answer should get more views (and upvotes).